# 404 connection Refused error on accessing REST API from ABAP

Tags: api, rest, abap

I am using REST API to Read data from sharepoint which is in excel file ,

on first access i am able to get data with 200 response , but when i am accessing it for second time its getting response code 404 Connection Refused .

please share the solution.

I am trying to read from excel sheet which is on sharepoint

Comment: A little bit of your code would be helpful

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.